# How to grep the pair of words from a file?

Tags: perl, bash, shell, awk, grep

I want to find the word pairs of file1 in the rows of file2. The words are separed by spaces in both the file. I want the pair of entries and there order does not matter means for the second line in file one the pair can be STG00001 STG00009 and STG00009 STG00001 and so on. Further, the multiple occurance on any word pair in file2 will be also okay.

Here is my list file File_1 with pair of words

```
STG00001 STG00001
STG00001 STG00009
STG00001 STG00012
STG00001 STG00010
STG00001 STG00011
```

This is the File_2, the file to be parsed

```
SML_00001 STG01479 STG00226 RSJ14430.1
SML_00001 STG00001 STG00009 RSJ14430.1
SML_00001 STG00010 STG00001 RSJ14430.1
SML_00002 STG02878 STG02733 RSJ13445.1
SML_00002 STG00001 STG00010 RSJ13445.1
SML_00002 STG02880 STG02733 RSJ13445.1
SML_00002 STG00001 STG00011 RSJ13445.1
```

The resultant file will be like

```
SML_00001 STG00001 STG00009 RSJ14430.1
SML_00001 STG00010 STG00001 RSJ14430.1
SML_00002 STG00001 STG00010 RSJ13445.1
SML_00002 STG00001 STG00011 RSJ13445.1
```

Comment: You should try to write some code and show us what you have done. Don't ask without trying - show some effort.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk 'NR == FNR {a[$1,$2]=1; a[$2,$1]=1; next} ($2 SUBSEP $3) in a' File_1 File_2
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a good starting point (untested, may have bugs...)

```
use File::Slurp;
use Regexp::Assemble;

my $ra = Regexp::Assemble->new;

for my $line (read_file('file1'), chomp => 1) {
   my @symbols = split ' ', $line;
   $ra->add(join ' ', @symbols);
   $ra->add(join ' ', reverse @symbols);
}

for my $line (read_file('file2') {
   say $line if $line =~ /$ra/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By sorting the fields, you can compare between file1 and file2.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh1, '<', 'file1.txt' or die $!;
my %words = map { join('', sort split) => 1} <$fh1>;
close $fh1 or die $!;

open my $fh2, '<', 'file2.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh2>) {
    my $key = join '', sort ( (split)[1,2] );
    print if $words{$key};
}
close $fh2 or die $!;
```